# swagger-maven-plugin triggers Javadoc warning: element value must be a constant expression (but it is!) in Java annotation

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, swagger-maven-plugin

Javadoc (via Maven) is giving me the following error in one my Java JAX-RS interface method signatures:

```
error: element value must be a constant expression
```

Here is my JAX-RS interface:

```
public interface FooResource {

  @Consumes(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_UTF_8)
  public void bar();

}
```

Javdoc gives the error for `@Consumes`. Here is the definition for `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_UTF_8`, which appears in `MyAppConstants` in the same project:

```
public static final String APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_UTF_8 =
    APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED + ";" + CHARSET_PARAMETER + "=UTF-8";
```

And here is the definition of `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`, which appears in `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`:

```
public final static String APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

And here is the definition of `CHARSET_PARAMETER`, which also appears in `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`:

```
public static final String CHARSET_PARAMETER = "charset";
```

Now I ask you: what about `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_UTF_8` is not constant at compile time?

The error message didn't say that I have to provide a *literal*. It said I had to provide a *constant*. So what about this is not a constant?

(I could almost swear that this worked at one time but suddenly stopped working.)

**Update:** *Found cause, but still don't understand.*

For some reason, merely including the `swagger-maven-plugin` in the POM will trigger this problem! My code doesn't change at all, but as soon as I add the following dependency, suddenly I get Javadoc warnings for my existing code!!!

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

How can a single dependency make Javadoc work differently on a code file? What is `swagger-maven-plugin` doing?

Comment: Sure the `final` keyword is still there? Without it, the class variable loses its constant characteristic.

Comment: Did you try the good old `clean install` already?

Comment: Yep, the `final` keyword is still there. Yep, I did a `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Crazy --- somehow `swagger-maven-plugin` is triggering this. But how? See updated question.

Comment: I'm getting the same error ("value must be a constant expression") on a constant, but my project is not using the swagger-maven-plugin.

Comment: Try doing a `mvn dependency:tree` and seeing if an old `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api` is getting pulled in via some other dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that this happens because `swagger-maven-plugin` transitively (via `io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.13`) an old version of the JAX-RS specification in `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1`. Note that the JAX-RS 2 artifact ID is `javax.ws.rs-api`, Maven doesn't realize that they are different versions of the same JAR, and pulls them both in as dependencies. I can only guess that `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api` in fact does not use constants for the variables in question. In any case, when I threw out `swagger-maven-plugin` and pulled in `io.swagger:swagger-annotations` (which was all I needed in this project for documentation), the problem went away.

See https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/543.